# Convert PS to PDF filed in C#

Tags: pdf, postscript

I have to make utility that converts PS files to PDF files.

Is there any FREE .net API available or any other solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid there is not much free can be found except of Ghostscript.

Take a look at [A Simple C# Wrapper for Ghostscript](http://www.mattephraim.com/blog/2009/01/06/a-simple-c-wrapper-for-ghostscript/).

If you want something more convenient then drop the FREE requirement.